# Name a variable or object based on the value of another variable in R

Tags: r

I read data files from a directory where I don't know the number or the name of the files. Each files a data frame (as parquet file). I can read that files. But how to name the results?

I would like to have something like a named list where the filename is the name of the element. I don't know how to do this in R. In Python I would use dictionaries like this

```
file_names = ['A.parquet', 'B.parquet']

all_data = {}

for fn in file_names:
    data = pd.read_parquet(fn)
    all_data[fn] = data
```

How can I solve this in R?

```
library("arrow")

file_names = c('a.parquet', 'B.parquet')

# "named vector"?
daten = c()

for (pf in file_names) {
    # name of data frame (filename without suffix)
    df_name <- strsplit(pf, ".", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]

    df <- arrow::read_parquet(pf)

    daten[df_name] = df
}
```

This doesn't work because I got this error

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what your code line does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tidyverse you would use `purrr`. This is basically the same as the `lapply()` or `sapply()` approach, but in a different ecosystem.

```r
library(arrow)
library(purrr)

file_names = c('a.parquet', 'B.parquet')

daten <- file_names %>% 
  set_names(tools::file_path_sans_ext) %>% 
  map(read_parquet)
```

You would access each list item through the usual ways.

```r
daten$a
daten$B

# or

daten[["a"]]
daten[["B"]]
```

**Explaination**

The pipe operator `%>%` is an extremely common thing to run into in R these days. It is from the `magrittr` package, but is also exported from various other `tidyverse` packages, including `purrr`.

The pipe takes the left hand argument and enters it as the first argument on the right side expression. So `f(x, y)` can be written as `x %>% f(y)`. This is useful to chain together expressions. R itself has a native pipe operator `|>` starting with version 4.1.0.

- `file_names` is an unnamed character vector of the file names.
- `set_names()` will make this a named vector by applying the function `file_path_sans_ext()` to `file_names`. This removes the file extension, so each element is named according to its name before the extension.
- `map()` will iterate over each element of the vector, returning a list named according to the names of the vector elements. Each iteration runs the `read_parquet` function on the input (the file name).

Comment: Can you explain your solution please, step by step. I don't understand it. I haven't asked for a mapping functionality. There is no problem with the for loop. My question was about the naming of the resulting objects. And what is `%>%` ?

Comment: @buhtz how is that for an explanation? Also, your comment of "I didn't ask for this" came off a bit rude. If you like the for loop, use the for loop. Somebody had already provided that answer. I was offering a streamlined solution using one of the most (if not the most) common frameworks in R today. Most R users would NOT use a for loop here. They would use either `lapply()` as the other answers shown, or `map()` as I showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can used named lists like so.

You can either use the names directly

```
sapply(file_names, arrow::read_parquet,USE.NAMES = TRUE,simplify = FALSE)
```

or set them after with whatever function you want to apply

```
setNames(lapply(file_names, arrow::read_parquet), str_extract(file_names, '(^.+)(\\.)'))
```

Comment: Don't forget the `library(stringr)` for the second solution! But may I suggest `tools::file_path_sans_ext` instead.